# Bash script automatitation name change using date

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, date, mv

I'm new to the shell/bash area. I've created this little script to change a name using the `date` command. The idea is to get something like this

```
1.txt=>2020-02.txt
```

And it works, but I get the old file name `2020-02-1.txt` added to the output.
This is my code so far:

```
# FOR LOOP TO RENAME FILES
cd /home/atlas/Documents/bash/CARPETA-ORIGEN
#UBICAR LA CARPETA
FILES=$(ls *.txt)
NEW="$(date +"%Y-%m")"
for FILE in $FILES  
  do
    echo "Renaming $FILE to new-$FILE"
    mv $FILE $NEW-$FILE
done
```

Comment: So what do you want to happen, exactly? presumably you are using a loop because the number of files is greater than 1. How do you propose to make the new names distinct?

Comment: Change the name of all the files with the date without the old name.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce your error. The result was:

- `1.txt` is renamed to `2020-02-1.txt`,
- `2.txt` is renamed to `2020-02-2.txt`,
- ...and so on.

If you want to remove the old filename/index from the result (which creates problems because of name clashes - there can only be one file as output), you can change your script to

```
# FOR LOOP TO RENAME FILES
cd /home/atlas/Documents/bash/CARPETA-ORIGEN
#UBICAR LA CARPETA
FILES=$(ls *.txt)
NEW="$(date +"%Y-%m")"
for FILE in $FILES  
  do
    echo "Renaming $FILE to new-$FILE"
    mv $FILE $NEW.txt
done
```

But I wouldn't recommend this, because you can only rename one `.txt` file per folder.
However, the output of the above script is

```
2020-02.txt
```